# Fargate vs Lambda, when to use which?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, serverless, aws-fargate

I'm pretty new to the whole Serverless landscape, and am trying to wrap my head around when to use Fargate vs Lambda.

I am aware that Fargate is a serverless subset of ECS, and Lambda is serverless as well but driven by events. But I'd like to be able to explain the two paradigms in simple terms to other folks that are familiar with containers but not that much with AWS and serverless.

Currently we have a couple of physical servers in charge of receiving text files, parsing them out, and populating several db tables with the results. Based on my understanding, I think this would be a use case better suited for Lambda because the process that parses out the text files is triggered by a schedule, is not long running, and ramps down when not in use.

However, if we were to port over one of our servers that receive API calls, we would probably want to use Fargate because we would always need at least one instance of the image up and running.

In terms of containers, and in very general terms would it be safe to say that if the container is designed to do:

```
docker run <some_input>
```

Then it is a job for Lambda.

But if the container is designed to do something like:

```
docker run --expose 80
```

Then it is a job for Fargate.

Is this a good analogy?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's the start of a good analogy. However Lambda also has limitations in terms of available CPU and RAM, and a maximum run time of 15 minutes per invocation. So anything that needs more resources, or needs to run for longer than 15 minutes, would be a better fit for Fargate.

Also I'm not sure why you say something is a better fit for Fargate because you "always need at least one instance running". Lambda+API Gateway is a great fit for API calls. API Gateway is always ready to receive the API call and it will then invoke a Lambda function to process it (if the response isn't already cached).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was also under the impression Lambda was made for containers when it is not. Lots to learn still!

Comment: [As of October 2018, Lambda supports 15 minutes per invocation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/)

Comment: @janDro they do run in dockers in the background, but we don't have access to them, they're "language dockers". That's where Fargate would come in.

Answer (score 26):

It is important to notice that with Lambda you don't need to build, secure, or maintain a container. You just worry about the code. Now as mentioned already, Lambda has a max run time limit and 3GB memory limit (CPU increases proportionally). Also if it is used sporadically it may need to be pre-warmed (called on a schedule) for extra performance.

Fargate manages docker containers, which you need to define, maintain and secure. If you need more control of what is available in the environment where your code runs, you could potentially use a container (or a server), but that again comes with the management. You also have more options on Memory/CPU size and length of time your run can take to run.

Even for an API server as you mentioned you could put API gateway in front and call Lambda.

Comment: Worth saying, even with the lambda limitations you can schedule a lambda to call several other lambdas, let's say to download and resize some images, so you can easilly workaround the limitations and have a pretty fast flow.

Comment: @Mojimi call a lambda which calls a lambda which calls a lambda, oh yeah I would like to see this working in a large project with multiple developers at work. NOT.

Answer (score 4):

As Mark has already mentioned, you can Lambda + API Gateway to expose your lambda function as API.
But lambda has significant limitations in terms of function executions. There are limitations on the programming languages supported, memory consumption and execution time (It was increased to 15 mins recently from the earlier 5 mins). This is where AWS Fargate can help by giving the benefits of both container world and Serverless (FaaS) world. Here you worry only about container (its CPU, memory requirements, IAM policies..) and leave the rest to Amazon ECS by choosing Fargate launch type. ECS will choose the right instance type, manage your cluster, it's auto scaling, optimum utilization.

Answer (score 2):

This is the right analogy, but it is not an exhaustive list to be able to explain the two paradigms.

In general, Lambda is more suitable for serverless applications. Its nature is a function-as-a-service (FaaS). It just does the simple tasks and that’s all. Don’t expect too much more.

It should be considered as the first option for serverless module. But it has more limitations and restrictions. Module architecture elaborated from functional and not-functional requirements, surrounded infrastructure and many other factors.

To make a decision minimum you must review the list of restrictions such as:

1. Portability
2. Environment control
3. Trigger type
4. Response time
5. Response size
6. Process time
7. Memory usage

These are the main factors. But the list hasn’t covered all the factors and restrictions to consider between both these serverless technologies.

To know more about I recommend this article https://greenm.io/aws-lambda-or-aws-fargate/