# when to use AWS Copilot or AWS SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, infrastructure-as-code, aws-copilot

In my organisation there are deployments using both SAM and Copilot. I am unable to work out what is the criteria or best use cases to use one or the other, and can't find any direct comparisons online?

So my question is are they comparable, if so when is it best to use each, and if not, why?

Answer (score 1):

Copilot deploys to AWS ECS. SAM deploys to AWS Lambda. So if you want to use ECS, then Copilot is an option. If you want to use Lambda then SAM is an option.

> So my question is are they comparable, if so when is it best to use each, and if not, why?

They aren't really comparable. They deploy to different AWS compute services with [different runtime architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275235/fargate-vs-lambda-when-to-use-which).

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense. Is there a similar tool for abstracting some of the architectural choices like SAM or Copilot for applications running on servers like EC2 applications etc?

Comment: You can't abstract the choice of using ECS or Lambda away, the two are completely different and you need to understand the differences and choose what is best for your application. Also, applications deployed directly on EC2 would be a totally different category than applications deployed to Lambda or ECS, so again you need to know what each AWS compute service does, and choose the one that is correct for your specific needs.